# How can I use 51Degreees data in a command line program to parse a UserAgent field?

Tags: c#, user-agent, httpmodule, 51degrees, iis-logs

I'm parsing some IIS Event Logs and need to analyze the UserAgent field.  I think that 51Degrees has the data I need, but this is implemented as a HTTP module.

- How do I interact with 51Degrees mobile device database with a C# command line application?

I do remember seeing a similar question before, starring it as a favorite, knowing that I'll need this in the future.  I suspect the question has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create that fairly simply using a Reader to create a Provider Object, then feeding user agents from the command line into the Provider, which produces BaseDeviceInfo Objects which can be used to query for properties. A more detailed explanation can be found at:

http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/20/51Degrees-mobi-Mobile-Detection-Outside-of-IIS.aspx

Comment: Links for working source are broken, where can the simple console sample be found?